# Setting a Symfony 2 configuration option based on (the value of) another one or the environment?

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

How can i set "disable_delivery" to a default value of `true` if the environment is "test"? Is this even possible?

Another question would be how can I set it based on another config option (like "username")?

```
$rootNode
    ->children()
        ->scalarNode('method')
            ->isRequired()
            ->cannotBeEmpty()
            ->validate()
                ->ifNotInArray($methods)
                ->thenInvalid('The method %s is not supported.')
            ->end()
        ->end()
        ->scalarNode('username')->isRequired()->cannotBeEmpty()->end()
        ->scalarNode('password')->isRequired()->cannotBeEmpty()->end()
        ->booleanNode('disable_delivery')->end()
    ->end()
;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better approach is to set this variable in your config_test.yml configuraiton file.

If you still want use default value: pass container instance to your Configuration class and use:

```
->booleanNode('disable_delivery')->defaultValue('test' === $this->container->get(‘http_kernel’)->getEnvironment() ? true : false)->end()
```

But it does not seems like good idea.

Same as for second question: use param in config file. It is much simpler and clearer for end user of your bundle (which you will be in two-three months).

Comment: Seems reasonable. For my second question I can't understand how implement that behavior in my `Configuration` class. Can you provide an example, i.e. setting `disable_delivery` to `false` if an `username` and `password` are provided?

Comment: I was talking about configuration parameters (http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/service_container.html#book-service-container-parameters). You can define it in parameters.ini|yml file and reuse them in config file. I see what did you mean, but have no answer yet.